# Cumulative values in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table like this:

```
Tournament Name        Start             End
Chess  A              2016-12-14     2017-01-31
Football B            2016-08-01     2017-02-15
....
```

I need to create a table that will tell me the number of ongoing tournaments per month. Something like:

```
Month-Year    Number of ongoing Tournaments
01-2016           2
02-2016           3
...
12-2016           4
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a list of months and then use a `join` or correlated subqueries:

```
select date_format(month_start, '%Y-%m') as yyyymm,
       (select count(*)
        from tournaments t
        where t.start <= m.month_start and
              t.end >= m.month_start + interval 1 month
       ) as ongoing
from (select date('2016-01-01') as month_start union all
      select date('2016-02-01') as month_start
     ) m;
```

Note:  This only counts tournaments that are valid for the entire month.  You can adjust the `where` clause if you want partial month tournaments to count.

Comment: but, if I need for all months from 2016-01-01 I will need to write something like  (select date('2016-01-01') as month_start union all
      select date('2016-02-01') as month_start union all
      select date('2016-03-01') as month_start union all
      ...
       select date('2016-12-01') as month_start
     ) m

right?

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga . . . Yes.  You would add the months you need to `m`.